# Removing an object from array based on properties value

Tags: javascript

I want to remove an object from my List array based on its properties value.
Right now I am using findIndex to see if there is an index ID matching my event.target.id.

This is an example of one of the objects in my list array:

```
{artist: "artist name",
genre: "RnB",
id: 1,
rating: 0,
title: "song name"}
```

This is my code:

```
  console.log(e.target.id);
  const list = this.state.playlist;
  list.splice(
    list.findIndex(function(i) {
      return i.id === e.target.id;
    }),
    1
  );

  console.log(list);
}
```

how ever, instead of it removing the clicked item from the array, it removes the last item, always.

When I do this:

```
const foundIndex = list.findIndex((i) => i.id === e.target.id)
console.log(foundIndex)
```

I get -1 back.

What's the problem here?

Comment: _"What's the problem here?"_ - there's no element with the value (and type) `e.target.id`. My guess: `typeof i.id !== typeof e.target.id`

Comment: With your edit... `i.id` is a number, `e.target.id` is a string. `===` also compares types.

Comment: Thanks guys! My mistake indeed was the difference of types! Changing === to == works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for this. Use it to filter out the objects from state where the id of the button doesn't match the id of the current object you're iterating over. `filter` will create a new array you can then update your state with rather than mutating the existing state (which is bad) which is what is currently happening.

Assuming you're using React here's a working example.

```js
const { Component } = React;

class Example extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      playlist: [
        {id: 1, artist: 'Billy Joel'},
        {id: 2, artist: 'Madonna'},
        {id: 3, artist: 'Miley Cyrus'},
        {id: 4, artist: 'Genesis'},
        {id: 5, artist: 'Jethro Tull'}
      ]
    };
  }

  // Get the id from the button (which will be
  // a string so coerce it to a number),
  // and if it matches the object id
  // don't filter it into the new array
  // And then update the state with the new filtered array
  removeItem = (e) => {
    const { playlist } = this.state;
    const { id } = e.target.dataset;
    const updated = playlist.filter(obj => {
      return obj.id !== Number(id);
    });
    this.setState({ playlist: updated });
  }

  render() {
    const { playlist } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {playlist.map(obj => {
          return (
            <div>{obj.artist}
              &nbsp;
              <button
                data-id={obj.id}
                onClick={this.removeItem}
              >Remove
              </button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }

};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Also, the findIndex method never finds an array item that meets the condition you provided, that's why it returns -1 and results in the removal of last item from your array.

Comment: _"Use filter for this..."_ - This does not solve the actual problem? OPs version would work with `==` or an explicit type cast...

Comment: The actual problem was the OP was trying mutate state (which is bad) and which `filter` solves. And which my question explains in detail.

Comment: _"The actual problem was the OP was trying mutate state..."_ - Yes, but that's just another thing to fix, _after_ the real actual problem (_"I get -1 back. What's the problem here?"_) is solved...

Comment: It's not another thing to fix, it's the only thing to fix. What is it about my answer you don't understand? I explained about not mutating state, and I explained that an id from a button would be a string and that it would have to coerced into a number. If you think my answer is inadequate downvote it or add your own answer that addresses the issues you think I've missed. @Andreas

Comment: I left my setState out of this function. At the end of the function i set playList: List. This is not mutating state as I first put my state in List right?
The problem here was that e.target.id was a string and i.id a number. Changing === to == was the solution!

Comment: @sneaker you are still mutating state.

Comment: @andy I have a List array which is the same as your updated array right? At the end of the function I write : setState(playList: List). Could you ellaborate why this still is mutating state? Thanks for your comments BTW!